# json sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

Tengo una columna declarada como `ntext` en una de mis tablas de **`SQL Server`**, donde se guarda un `json` obtenido de una api de un tercero.  Estoy tratando de recorrerlo directamente con **`SQL Server`** pero no encuentro la manera, el solo hecho de ejecutar la comprobación como se indica en la documentación:

```
ISJSON(SELECT json  FROM Multi.dbo.DataIn);
```

me arroja **error**:

> Could not find stored procedure 'ISJSON'

Cómo se soluciona ésto? no encuentro la solución

Answer (score 0):

`ISJSON` es una función introducida en SQL Server 2016. En versiones anteriores no existe esa función. La única solución es actualizar.

Aunado a eso, deberías de actualizar la columna para que el tipo de dato sea `NVARCHAR(MAX)` en vez de `NTEXT`. El mantener un tipo de dato obsoleto te puede impedir actualizar a las nuevas versiones.

Comment: `ISJSON` es una función que está desde SQL Server 2016. Por otro lado, aún si el op estuviera usando esta versión, recibiría el mismo error porque la sintaxis está incorrecta. Y tomando el punto de `ntext`, `ISJSON` no soporta ese tipo de dato

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración. Por alguna razón, quitaron a que versiones aplican los MS Docs.

Comment: sí, no sé en qué están pensando con el cambio que hicieron en la documentación, las versiones válidas son importantísimas. De todas formas, mi comentario a tu respuesta va más a que el op podría estar usando SQL Server 2016+, y recibiría el mismo error, porque lo está usando mal

Comment: Gracias, igual ya verifiqué y la compatibilidad es 2012, es decir, no puedo usar esto a menos que actualice como sugieres, sin embargo no depende de mi. Tendré que ver cómo resuelvo usando cron

Comment: Tal vez esta serie de artículos te ayuden en algo, aunque estén en inglés. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/